# How can I grep within a repository in Github?

Tags: github

In a repository in Github, without cloning or pulling it to my local machine, can I find files which contain some words, i.e. do things similar to `grep`?

I am browsing the repository in my web browser, and want to know if it is possible to do the above in my browser.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There's a search box at the top of the page. It defaults to searching *This repository*.

[image: Screenshot]